# Rails3 routing: Resource with namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible to define a namespace parameter when defining my routes, like this:

```
resource :account, :namespace => :account do
    resources :comments
end
```

So `/account/comment` calls `Account::CommentsController` instead of just `CommentsController`. Just as a note, the  `:namespace`-option above does NOT seem to work.

I can of course just add `:controller => 'account/comments'` to the comments resources, but having a lot of nested resources, this is not very DRY.

Is there better way?

Thanks guys - you rock!

Answer (score 5):

Okay, after some digging around I seem to have found a solution:

```
resource :account, :controller => 'account' do
    scope :module => 'account' do
        resources :comments
        ...
    end
end
```

This results in:

`/account/comments` being linked to `Account::CommentsController` while still being able to acccess the regular CRUD-methods using `/account`

Comment: Is this the cleaner way to do is? It should be another way. Anyway, thanks for this